# Is it possible for this .submit() to wait until other event is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert2

I have this code written in jquery, and also using sweetalert

```
$(document).on('click', '#save-task', function() {
  let category      = $('#select-or-enter-category').val();
  let url           = $('#select-or-enter-url').val();

  data = {
    categoryName: category
  };

  axios_post('/check/existing/category', data, function(data) {
    if (data.categoryName == null) {
      $('#cat-id').attr('value', '');

      swal({
        title: "Notice!",
        text: "The category name you entered doesn't exist! Would you like to save it?",
        icon: "warning",
        buttons: true,
        dangerMode: true,
      })
      .then((willSave) => {
        if (willSave) {
          let val = $('#select-or-enter-category').val();

          if (val != '') {
            axios_post('/save-category', {category: val}, function(data) {
              saveCategory(data);
            });
          }
        } else {
          swal("We're not able to save new category!");
        }
      });
    }
  });

  data = {
    url: url
  };

  axios_post('/check/existing/url', data, function(data) {
    if (data.url == null) {
      $('#cat-id').attr('value', '');

      swal({
        title: "Notice!",
        text: "The url you entered doesn't exist! Would you like to save it?",
        icon: "warning",
        buttons: true,
        dangerMode: true,
      })
      .then((willSave) => {
        if (willSave) {
          let val = $('#select-or-enter-url').val();

          if (val != '') {
            // Send a request via post to the server
            axios_post('/save-url', {url: val}, function(data) {
              saveUrl(data);
            });
          }
        } else {
          swal("We're not able to save new category!");
        }
      });
    }
  });

  $('#add-task-form').submit();
});
```

The code above work fine except that this `$('#add-task-form').submit();` part will submit in the middle `sweetalert` event ending with the `sweetalert` not interacting properly with the user.

Is it possible for this `$('#add-task-form').submit();` to wait until the sweetalert event is done in there part?

Comment: Your submit function is out of the `.then` function, what do you expect?

Comment: Call `.submit()` in the callback of the sweet alert.

Answer (score 0):

You should do "$('#add-task-form').submit();" in ".then" block.

If you have to wait for more than 1 promise block, you can save all the promises in an array and do the submit on "Promise.all()" (details at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). Your calls to "swal(..." returns a promise, which you can save in a variable.